# Estimate time for mean reversion of two time series

Tags: r, time-series, cointegration

The objective is to identify if two time series are cointegrated and then calculate their time for mean reversion using half life of mean reversion.

How is `half life of mean reversion` related to `Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process`?

Which R package would you suggest to perform the above experiments (cointegration and half life of mean reversion)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Orstein-Uhlenbeck is a stochastic process which tends to drift, or revert, back to its long term mean (AKA mean-reversion).  The 'half life of mean reversion' is the average time it will take a process to get pulled half-way back to the mean.

Look at [urca](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/urca/index.html) for the cointegration test.

For half life of mean reversion check out these two articles:

[Exploring mean reversion and cointegration with Zorro and R: part 1](http://robotwealth.com/exploring-mean-reversion-and-cointegration-with-zorro-and-r-part-1/)

[Exploring mean reversion and cointegration: part 2](http://robotwealth.com/exploring-mean-reversion-and-cointegration-part-2/)

The author computes the half life of mean reversion as:

```
y <- audnzd # Forex Australian Dollar/New Zealand Dollar
y.lag <- lag(y, -1)
delta.y <- diff(y)

df <- cbind(y, y.lag, delta.y)
df <- df[-1 ,] #remove first row with NAs

regress.results <- lm(delta.y ~ y.lag, data = df)

lambda <- summary(regress.results)$coefficients[2]
half.life <- -log(2)/lambda
```